# Dashboard broken into list of links

Tags: php, dashboard

After (I think) php became outdated by a new version of Wordpress, my dashboard no longer functions. It shows up as a list of links (all representing dashboard features), none of which work.[image: broken dashboard]

Updating php got rid of the request to update the database when logging in, but the dashboard is still quite borked.

Ideas?